# How do I convert a string with operand signs to a double?

Tags: java, string, math, double

In java the following code works:

```
double a = 15.5+0.5; 
System.out.println(a);
```

This will print `16.0`.

So why does the following return a runtime error:

```
String a = "15.5+0.5";
Double b = Double.parseDouble(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

How can I get the second example to not give an error and behave like the first when converting the string to double and calculating a value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form
look at this question and awnser should be it right?

Comment: So is there a way to perform expression evaluation of a string?

Answer (score 0):

`parseDouble`, `parseInteger` etc. don't perform expression **evaluation**, they just perform conversions from the string representation of some value to the numeric representation (so `"5.0"` gets converted to `5.0`).

See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) for the precise definition of `parseDouble`'s behaviour.

---

If you want to perform expression evaluation, you could look into Reverse Polish Notation and the Shunting Yard algorithm, or ideally a [library designed for this](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx). Alternatively, you can use [a more "hacky" solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).